# Posted form with file upload occasionally does not have files

Tags: php, html, forms, post, file-upload

I've been seeing some failures in PHP to find files attached in a form being submitted. It works about 80% of the time, then split between no files being attached, or only one or two.

The use case is for vehicle checkout, vehicles have pictures taken and then submitted for archival purposes. An example (6 photos are required, 1 is extra) of the code is:

```
<form name="fForm" action="fleet-check-out-update.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post" id="fleet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
.....
<tr>
<th>Driver Side - Bumper to Bumper:</th>
<td><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="16000000">
<input type="file" name="attachment5" id ="attachment5" class="file_1" style="width:375px;"/></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<th>Interior/Cab - Clean interior:</th>
<td><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="16000000">
<input type="file" name="attachment6" id ="attachment6" class="file_1" style="width:375px;"/></td>
</tr>
```

On the backend, this line starts the failures when a failure occurs:

```
$name = $_FILES["attachment5"]['name'];
```

With a PHP Notice:  Undefined index: attachment5 notice.

Files would then get uploaded to S3 via:

```
 if ($s3->putObjectFile($tmp, $bucket . "/fleet/$nowstamp2/$number", $name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ))
```

However since there is no file data at $name, this would fail.

In cases of failure, all non-file post data (text) still comes over.

Initially, file size limits in PHP caused failures, but increasing the data allowed fixed that. Devices are Android or iOS phones- meaning each picture is 4MB+ direct from the phone. I don't think there is any way to easily force a smaller size picture from the web page while not impeding the usability- but if there is I'd be interested in it.

I would like to eliminate this bug from occuring, but I am not sure if it due to the HTML/PHP on the server, or if the end user's phone is timing out/failing for some reason due to memory/connection quality/some other reason.

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: share your file upload code

Comment: not in comment delete it from here and paste it in you question summary by editing question.

Comment: In addition to the filesize limit, did you set up the `post_max_size`? This will generally cause no files to be attached if the full size of all the files exceeds that limit.

Comment: Yes, post_max_size and upload_max_filesize are set to 48M, max_file_uploads is 20, default_socket_timeout is 60 seconds,  max_execution_time is 600 seconds, max_input_vars is 10,000, memory_limit is 128M. Increasing the size limits stopped any errors or failures due to sizing- at 7 pics at 5MB each they dont break 48M